# POSTGRES 9.4: Function parameter as empty array

Tags: postgresql, array, parameter

I'm trying to create an empty array as a parameter so it's optional. I want to be able to call it without having the need to give a 2nd and 3rd parameter. Can somebody help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.fnc_calc(
    p_par1 text,
    p_par2 text DEFAULT NULL::text,
    p_par3 par_type DEFAULT[] '{}'::par_type[]
)
RETURNS void AS
```

When I call it like this:

```
select * from myschema.fnc_calc('what_the_hell');
```

I get this message:

```
ERROR:  function myschema.fnc_calc(unknown, unknown, par_type) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

BTW, this is has nothing to do with the public schema or calling it from a different schema. All the references are right. I checked this. I'm thinking that the declaration of the array parameter (p_par3) in the function should be something different (maybe not subscribe to an array with the '[]', but leaving it out doesn't work as it requires the parameter to be populated). Any ideas?

Comment: You wouldn't get and error message like that when calling the function with a single parameter. And the function definition has a syntax error. Please fix your question. Present your *actual* function definition and call.

Answer (score 2):

Your `p_par3` is defined as `par_type` which is not the declaration for an array. You need to define it as `par_type[]` if that should be a parameter that is an array.

The following works for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_calc(
    p_par1 text,
    p_par2 text DEFAULT NULL::text,
    p_par3 par_type[] DEFAULT '{}'::par_type[]
)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
  select 42;
$$ 
language sql;
```

---

Also: `default[]` is wrong - your whole statement will not work.